# Tcl: Sourcing a File.tcl from Another Directory

Tags: tcl

I created a main tcl file in a specified directory and I want to source another tcl file, which is not in a same directory of the main one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the complete path to the Tcl file as argument to `source`.

Example: your main file (`main.tcl`) is in `/`, the other file (`other.tcl`) is in `/foo/bar/`.

```
source /foo/bar/other.tcl
```

As always, one must be careful with backslashes separating directories on the Windows platform. If the path is `C:\foo\bar\`, one must either escape the backslashes (`C:\\foo\\bar\\` or `{C:\foo\bar\}`) or replace them with regular slashes, as in `C:/foo/bar/`. If the path is relative to the current directory, one can side-step the issue by using `file join foo bar`.

Documentation: [filename](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/filename.htm), [source](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/source.htm)

Comment: I know it. But I can use this command, when the source file is in a directory as same as the main file.

Comment: I understood! But it does't work! The Tcl doesn't accept the complete path! It just works when the main and source file are in a same directory. I can just use a local path.

Comment: @MuhammadAliRostampour: can you post your invocation of `source`, including the path?

Comment: Main file: `D:\University_Master\Thesis\Programming\runMDOF_ETA.tcl` and Source file: `D:\University_Master\OpenSees\MDOF_0_Parameters.tcl`

Comment: My problem is that I used "\" instead of "/" :D Thank you!